# integrating mixare into Android app

Tags: java, android, augmented-reality

I wrote an Android App using the Mixare ([link to mixare project](http://www.mixare.org/)) Framework (for augmented reality).

The first step was to get the App running with my own data source. This was pretty simple since you simply have to create a new Intent for the mixare content like this:

```
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("http://myserver:8080/myData"), "application/mixare-json");
    startActivity(i);
```

The problem is that this code simply makes a call to the mixare App on your Android device.

I want to modify the mixare view and integrate the whole source code into my App (it is licensed under GPLv3).

Do I have to use the mixare code as a library? What changes would I have to do to my AndroidManifest.xml for creating a new Intent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out, that my question is not necessarily a mixare problem.

The Solution for integrating an Android app into another one is using the first one as a library.

For anyone who has not done this before [this article](http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/integrate-zxing-barcode-scanner-into-your-android-app-natively-using-eclipse/) helped me a lot. It explains how to integrate *zxing barcode scanner* into an Android app natively.

Comment: I'm trying to integrate mixare into my android app. I use intellij idea and I'm adding just mixare-library folder into my libs. If I download mixare from market it works but I want to run it through my app. How should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to integrate mixare into your app then the whole app must be released under the GPLv3 license.

At the moment it's not possible for external plugins to alter the mixare view (i.e. using own icons or modifying the layout), but there are plans to do so, even though there are no estimates.

If you are interested I would suggest you propose your suggested approach to the developer [discussion group](http://groups.google.com/group/mixare-development).

HTH,
Daniele - mixare team

Comment: Yes thx, my app is licensed under the GPLv3.
But my question was, since I have all the source code for mixare, I can modify anything, right? I only need to integrate this modified mixare code into my app. (according 
to 4. at http://www.mixare.org/usage/)
So my question was, how to do that?

Comment: I'm not user I get your question. Do you want to use a different activity when starting from the launcher?

Comment: Sorry, if I can't express myself in the right way. I'm quiet new to the Android development. So lets say I want to change something in the POIMarker class to modify the appearance of a marker. How would I integrate this modified mixare code into my app?

Comment: @ Daniele : is it possible to define different events for click of the markers than opening the web page ? Thanks a lot for your answer. I am trying to use mixare to show some POIs . On click i want to display some more details of that place but within the same screen as a dialogue .

Comment: @Daniele could you explain a little what should I need to run mixare through my app (without installing mixare app from market)